# Get the documents of order id 1 that are not in order id 2 MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I have this set of documents

```
{_id: ObjectId(""),orderid:1,productName:"Iphone 13"}
{_id: ObjectId(""),orderid:1,productName:"Xiaomi 11"}
{_id: ObjectId(""),orderid:1,productName:"Pocophone F1"}
{_id: ObjectId(""),orderid:1,productName:"Samsung S22"}
{_id: ObjectId(""),orderid:2,productName:"Iphone 13"}
{_id: ObjectId(""),orderid:2,productName:"Xiaomi 11"}
```

I am trying to get the product names that are in order 1 but not in order 2, my mongodb query was:

```
{orderid:{$eq:orderid-1,$ne:orderid}}
```

but it does not work, then I was trying with an aggregate op like:

```
{
    $match: {orderid:{$gte:orderid-1}} //this is because allways a will try to get the products name in max orderid - 1 to get that resutl with the last 2 orders
    $group:{
       _id: {productname: '$productName'}
       orders:{$push:'$orderid'}
       total:{$sum:1}
    }
    //Then here i'm trying to get just de maxorderid-1 docs that just have total equal 1 but i cant achive the result.
}
```

Thanks you so much for your support and answers.

Comment: something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/w0tSJfZ3JwH

Comment: nope this gives me the whole products with orderid 1 and i just want the products with orderid 1 that are not in orderid 2

Comment: I think found the answer is like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/RVuAm-Jg-UZ

Comment: I was attempting something here : https://mongoplayground.net/p/M0hhtL6qJ8A   , but not working not sure why ... , it has to work in general ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can try something like this:

- First `$group` by `productName` and store `orderids` in an array
- The `$match` by values in the array: `$and` condition where exists `1` and not `2`.
- And then rebuild the objects using `$unwind` and `$project` with the axuliar field `root` saved in the `$group` stage

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$productName",
      "orderids": {
        "$push": "$orderid"
      },
      "root": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "orderids": 1
        },
        {
          "orderids": {
            "$ne": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$root"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$root._id",
      "orderid": "$root.orderid",
      "productName": "$root.productName"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NDGet8oYfLC)

Also, if you only want the `productName`, that value is stored in the `id` of the group, soy uo don't need the last two stages. Like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1DYz46CypMf)

Comment: Thanks a lot this is so helpful the first one is the answer to my question but also like me the second one